# String from integer8

Tags: arrays, string, ada

I'm using a library in ada which contains many types :

```
type Int8 is range -8 ** 7 .. 2 ** 7 - 1;
subtype T_Name_String is Int8;
type T_Name_String_Fixed20 is array (range 1..20) of T_Name_String ;
```

And there is a record with :

```
type The_Record is record
   name : T_Name_String_Fixed20;
   -- and others
end record;
```

I can't change that, I don't know why there are using `Int8` for ada strings but I'm not able to initiate the field `name`. I've try :

```
-- First try:
MyRecord.name = "hello               ";
-- Error : expected type T_Name_String_Fixed20 found a string type

-- Second try
Ada.Strings.Fixed.Move(Target => MyRecord.name;
                       Source => "hello               "
```

Comment: Typo? should almost certainly have been `type Int8 is range -2 ** 7 .. 2 ** 7 - 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to the answer from @Shark8, if you want to convert between real Strings and T_Name_String_Fixed20, you also have to convert between Character and T_Name_String. Here is some example code for that:

```
subtype String20 is String (1 .. 20);

function To_Name (S : String20)
return T_Name_String_Fixed20
-- Assumes that all characters in S have 'Pos < 128.
is
   Result : T_Name_String_Fixed20;
begin
   for K in Result'Range loop
      Result(K) := T_Name_String (Character'Pos(S(K)));
   end loop;
   return Result;
end To_Name;

function To_String (N : T_Name_String_Fixed20)
return String20
-- Assumes that all values in N are >= 0.
is
   Result : String20;
begin
   for K in Result'Range loop
      Result(K) := Character'Val (N(K));
   end loop;
   return Result;
end To_String;
```

You can test this by, for example,

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (To_String (To_Name ("Hello crazy world!!!")));
```

Note that the string argument to To_Name has to be exactly 20 characters long, as I have written that function (subtype String20). If you prefer, you can of course modify the function to take also shorter strings and eg. pad with blanks.

Comment: OK for ASCII but not Latin1

Comment: Ah, you are right, Simon, and mea culpa, I did not test that. The error is that the addition and subtraction of T_Name_String'First make the computation use the Int8 type, but in To_Name the Character'Pos does not fit in that type (if > 127), and in To_String the result of the subtraction does not fit in that type. I edited the code in my answer (and, this time, tested it for Latin1 characters).

Comment: What we don’t know is what the external system makes of characters with `’Pos` > 127!

Comment: I just realized that my translation does not map the Character'Pos values 0..127 to the T_Name_String values 0..127, which is probably expected. Silly me. So let's just assume that we have only 0 .. 127, in which case the translation is simple. I will change my suggested code to be such, and try to be less hurried in my future answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the big problem there is the terrible and uninformative naming.
But, taking a look at the error you're not supplying it with a value of `T_Name_String_Fixed20`, which you've posted as a "`type T_Name_String_Fixed20 is array (range 1..20) of T_Name_String ;`", so an array.

That array-type has elements of `T_Name_String`, which is a "subtype-renaming" of `Int8` ("`subtype T_Name_String is Int8;`") -- so `type Int8 is range -8 ** 7 .. 2 ** 7 - 1;`, which is range `-2_097_152..127`.

So, combining that all together, `name`'s type is `array(1..20) of range -2_097_152..127`... try:

```
 MyRecord.name := (1..20 => 3);
```